# Mutating a mutable collection using map?

Tags: scala

If you have a mutable data structure like an `Array`, is it possible to use `map` operations or something similar to change its values?

Say I have `val a = Array(5, 1, 3)`, what the best way of say, subtracting 1 from each value? The best I've come up with is

```
for(i <- 0 until a.size) { a(i) = a(i) - 1 }
```

I suppose way would be make the array a `var` rather than a `val` so I can say

```
a = a map (_-1)
```

edit: fairly easy to roll my own if there's nothing built-in, although I don't know how to generalise to other mutable collections

```
scala> implicit def ArrayToMutator[T](a: Array[T]) = new {
     |   def mutate(f: T => T) = a.indices.foreach {i => a(i) = f(a(i))}
     | }
ArrayToMutator: [T](a: Array[T])java.lang.Object{def mutate(f: (T) => T): Unit}

scala> val a = Array(5, 1, 3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(5, 1, 3)

scala> a mutate (_-1)

scala> a
res16: Array[Int] = Array(4, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't care about indices, you want the `transform` method.

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.transform(_+1)
res1: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int] = WrappedArray(2, 3, 4)

scala> a
res2: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4)
```

(It returns a copy of the wrapped array so that chaining transforms is more efficient, but the original array is modified as you can see.)

Comment: Cool, I thought there must be something. Any ideas on comparative efficiency between this, pimping the library as in the question, or using a normal function?

Comment: @Luigi Plinge - If you specialize your version and are using primitive types, yours will be faster (unless you hit a specialization bug, of which there are a few).  Otherwise the library is just as fast as you.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `foreach` since you don't really want to return a modified collection, you want to perform a task for each element.  For example:

```
a.indices.foreach{i => a(i) = a(i) - 1}
```

or

```
a.zipWithIndex.foreach{case (x,i) => a(i) = x - 1}
```

Comment: `indices` seems like a useful method